# .htaccess: Remove extension and force traling slash (seo friendly)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been playing about with my `.htaccess` file and so far that's doesn't work.

I'm trying to force the `.www` prefix, while removing the .html extension and adding/force a trailing slash at the end of URL.

Example (with `test.html` file):

http://www.domain.com/test.html
http://www.domain.com/test
http://domain.com/test.html
http://domain.com/test
**= http://www.domain.com/test/**

My `.htaccess`:

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laforgenumerique.fr$
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

#REMOVE DOT HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

#FORCE TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

#CUSTOM ERROR DOCUMENT
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/404.html
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.laforgenumerique.fr/404.html
```

Please help!

Host: OVH

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
#REMOVE DOT HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

#FORCE TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

It seems that you are trying to mix two separate rules. 
[L] suffix means that this is the last rule; all rules below will be skipped even if they are suitable.
You may try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.$1
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1/ [L]
```

Comment: What is `www.$1.html`?

Comment: What if the last rule is RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1/ [L]